# STM32F103R6 (Cortex-M3) trouble with rising edge detection

Tags: stm32, embedded

I'm using Proteus 8.6 for simulation of STM32F103R6 microcontroller with ports C0 connected to a LED and port C1 connected to a button. I'm trying to capture the rising edge of the button so that it switches the LED on every third click. I'm getting a weird behavior because it switches the LED on the 2nd click(rising) and it turns the LED off on the click after that(falling). I've tried 3 other configurations, using pull down input mode, but capturing the falling edge and using pull up input mode and capturing both rising and falling edges with button connected to the ground. Only configuration that gives me weird behavior is when the button is connected to power and I'm using pull down input mode while capturing the rising edge. Here's my code:

```
    #include <stdint.h>

#define RCC_APB2ENR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40021000 + 0x18)))
#define GPIOC_CRL (*((uint32_t *) (0x40011000 + 0x00)))
#define GPIOC_ODR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40011000 + 0x0C)))
#define GPIOC_IDR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40011000 + 0x08)))
#define AFIO_EXTICR1 (*((uint32_t *) (0x40010000 + 0x08)))

#define IOPCEN (0x01 << 4)
#define AFIOEN (0x01 << 0)

#define MODE_OUT_2MHZ 0x02
#define CNF_GP_OUT_PUSH_PULL 0x00

#define MODE_IN 0x00
#define CNF_GP_IN_PULL 0x08

#define EXTI_PORT_C 0x02

void init_GPIOC()
{
    RCC_APB2ENR |= IOPCEN | AFIOEN;

    GPIOC_CRL |= MODE_OUT_2MHZ << (4 * 0) | CNF_GP_OUT_PUSH_PULL << (2 + 4 * 0);
    GPIOC_ODR = 0x0;



    GPIOC_CRL |= MODE_IN << (4 * 1) | CNF_GP_IN_PULL << (2 + 4 * 1);
    //GPIOC_ODR |= 0x01 << 1;



    AFIO_EXTICR1 |= EXTI_PORT_C << (4 * 1);
}

#define EXTI_IMR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40010400 + 0x00)))
#define EXTI_RTSR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40010400 + 0x08)))
#define EXTI_FTSR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40010400 + 0x0C)))
#define EXTI_PR (*((uint32_t *) (0x40010400 + 0x14)))

#define MR_NOT_MASKED 0x01
#define TR_ENABLED 0x01
#define TF_ENABLED 0x01

void init_EXTI()
{


    EXTI_IMR |= MR_NOT_MASKED << 1;
    EXTI_RTSR |= TR_ENABLED << 1;
    //EXTI_FTSR |= TF_ENABLED << 1;
}

#define NVIC_ISER0 (*((uint32_t *) (0xE000E100 + 0x00)))

#define SETENA 0x01

void init_NVIC()
{


    NVIC_ISER0 = SETENA << 7;
}

int counter = 3;


void process_button_click()
{

        if(--counter == 0)
        {
            // Stanje diode menjamo na svaki treci pritisak dugmeta
            GPIOC_ODR ^= 0x01;
            counter = 3;

        }

}


void exti_1_handler()
{


    if((EXTI_PR & 0x02) != 0)
    {
        EXTI_PR = 0x02;

        process_button_click();

    }
}

int main()
{
    init_GPIOC();
    init_EXTI();
    init_NVIC();

    while (1)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Be careful using simulation for this.  Even if the simulation is faithful, buttons in the real world exhibit contact bounce.  To have a useful system you will need to implement de-bouncing, often something like ignoring a button for some period of time after seeing the event you desire.

Comment: I've tried adding a debouncing period, even going up to 500.000 units in an empty for loop, but only thing it does is miss a couple of button clicks, it doesn't solve the rising/falling edge problems.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using noisy pushbuttons directly with interrupts may not be a good idea. What may happen in this case is that it thinks first edge already is pending when you enable interrupts. And due to noise, both falling and rising edge interrupts get latched as pending. Perhaps most important is to know that if no interrupts has happened, button state has not changed. When interrupt has happened, button state has glitched but if you wait for some time without new intetrupts you can believe that it has stabilized. You may want to disable further interrupts for the stabilization period. And a timer can be useful for determining time or actually executing the button callback in timer interrupt if further interrupts do not restart it. It all depends on if you want to just use pushbuttons, or use pushbutton to simulate interrupt signals.

Comment: One potential method (if you require really time timing for some reason where polling won't work) is to have the first interrupt trigger a timer with an interrupt that checks the state of the pin sometime in the future so you can compare the two states, or set yet another timer interrupt so you can compare all three states over time, etc.